# Making a wallpaper with a function on Android

Tags: android, flutter, wallpaper

The idea of my app, is to make a wallpaper, which I guess has a functioning clock (time engine) on it, and it would print when the current school hour ends/starts. Obviously, that's not it, and there will be more features in it, but my question is with what could I make it. Basically, the problem is not knowing how to make it (with what) nor how would it work.

Flutter would be good, if possible, since I'm currently learning it, so this would be a good starting project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is not possible with flutter ... google for "android live wallpaper" i'm pretty sure that you have to extend `WallpaperService`  and implement own `WallpaperService.Engine`

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out, sounds promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to write code that will change background of your phone and for you clock you need to create widget clock that you can easily add from widget options

Comment: What do you think I should write the code with, is Flutter an option, since I've found nothing even similar to this, made with Flutter, since it's so young?

Comment: Look Flutter is new doesn't have that much control over android so I will suggest go with native start coding in kotlin in Android studio for this project